# How do I find good games to memorise for the openings I play?

Tags: opening, memorization

I have read other questions like this and I find people responding "just doing tactics is less effort and helps more". But personally, I find it really easy to memorise things, so I'm interested in trying it anyway. So please consider this question under the assumption that memorising games is the goal, rather than suggesting better ways to study (unless someone feels very strongly, I guess). Of course I will be studying the game properly first, so I'm not memorising without understanding or anything, the point of the question is just about finding good games.

I thought I would just find some recent games of super-GMs and study those, but I quickly realised they are probably a bit complex for my level (2000 rapid on Lichess).

Instead, since I currently play the Caro-Kann/Open Sicilian/Ruy Lopez almost exclusively, I decided I would find an opening book and look at the games they show as examples. I skimmed through Houska's Caro-Kann book, but it looks like most of the games might have come from Blitz, (as soon as theory ends there are some pretty bad blunders from both sides in the games that I looked at).

So where should I be looking for exemplar games? There are plenty of miniatures etc. for the Open Sicilian and the Ruy, but I am mostly struggling to find a good source for Caro-Kann games, since most GMs seem to stick with the Najdorf, and I am assuming I'm not good enough yet to start playing complex Sicilians.

Comment: At sub-master level, I would consider games with "blunders" as a feature, not a bug. By those, you get a feeling for the tactics that are possible in that opening and why certain moves work or don't. In flawless games, you might never get to see these crucial details, only the more complex shadow boxing done to evade them - in other words, you would essentially end up with the Super-GM games you judged as too complex to understand yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple suggestion: [Lichess.](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard)

- Tons of games shown, just enter opening moves.
- Stockfish addable on the fly.
- Hit "book" (button down left) for master games.

Answer (score 1):

You can't memorize chess. There have been players with insane memories and they tend to take the opposite approach (Pillsbury comes to mind).

It will help you a lot more to learn the ideas behind the moves.

However, a GM once told me to memorize one game per day. Play a game and then look it up on a database like chessgames.com or https://www.365chess.com/. See how your favorite player played the same position. Learn the game and learn why they made the moves they did.

Comment: your first and third paragraphs seem to contradict each other. I shouldn't memorise games -> a GM told you to memorise games?

Comment: Not really. It's what someone else said not what I said. Besides, memorizing one game isn't the same thing as trying to memorize the entire game of chess.

Comment: not too sure what memorising 'chess' (whatever you think that means) has to do with the question then if you agree it's not the same... an answer was also selected about 5 months ago that covers pretty much what your GM suggestion was anyway

Comment: The question is literally "How do I find good games to memorise..." (sic). I don't understand how you think I didn't answer the question when I provided two very large databases.

Comment: The other answer is pretty terrible. It only includes one database mostly composed of low quality online games between beginners. On top of that he doesn't really say much pf anything and isn't even talking in complete sentences.

Comment: lichess hosts a master games database, as the answer implies when it says "master games"... and on an unrelated note I am honestly astounded you tried to be passive aggressive by placing a [sic] next to memorise... are you aware America is not the only country that speaks english?

Comment: Lichess has some master games but it's far from a complete database and certainly not on the level of the databases I mentioned. At the very least, you have to agree I'm adding something that the original answerer didn't include and that by itself proves you wrong.

Comment: And by the way, British English is frequently wrong but that's another debate for another time.

Comment: what a strange hill to die on... anyway thanks for clarifying your intriguing answer. I will definitely consider changing the accepted answer to yours